# How to disable the title of DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-datepicker

```
void showDatePickerDailog() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, datePickerListener,
        cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePicker.setCancelable(false);
    ((ViewGroup) datePicker.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    long timeadj = 24*60*60*1000;
    datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate((new Date().getTime())+timeadj);
    datePicker.show();
}
```

I tried the above code but it crashed. How can I disable the `datepicker` header?

Comment: can you add the crash log please?

Comment: datePicker.setTitle("");

Comment: i tried it  datePicker.setTitle(""); does not work

Comment: try `datePicker.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: @DhavalPatel it worked.thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

To Remove Dialog Title add below code snippet before `dialog.show()`.

```
datePicker.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score -1):

`AlertDialog` have `setCustomHeader` method, using it and set a custom view with `zero` width, `zero` height. It will work

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
timePickerDialog.setCustomTitle(linearLayout);
```